# Magento 2.2.4 The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists

Tags: magento2, admin, category, url-rewrite, magento2.2.4

when I have the category in product assign and saving category below error showing

> The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that
>   already exists. 
>  To resolve this conflict, you can either change the
>   value of the URL Key field (located in the Search Engine Optimization
>   section) to a unique value or change the Request Path fields in all
>   locations listed below:

[image]

and my **exception.log** error log is

[image]

Comment: You have duplicate URLs.

Comment: @vitoriodachef but how can solve this issue

Comment: @vitoriodachef and exception.log is `URL key for specified store already exists. `

Comment: Wich magento version are you using?

Comment: @ChiragPatel magento 2.2.4

Comment: There are so may issue is already reported on stack & GitHub and other community.  and there are so many solutions for that and which one is correct it is to difficult choosing the right one. but i see one issue is reported on github which one help to you i think. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7298

Comment: @ChiragPatel thank you for comment but i have not found proper answer

Comment: @RakeshDonga see my answer, to resolve your issue there is only one way to play with the database. so I have share one method which one helpful to you. there is also so many other methods is available for that.

Comment: @ChiragPatel useful link is : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154139/how-to-delete-and-regenerate-url-rewrites-in-magento-2

Comment: @RakeshDonga Thanks

Comment: @RakeshDonga I have get same error while saving category. Do you have fixed this issue ?

The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists.
To resolve this conflict, you can either change the value of the URL Key field (located in the Search Engine Optimization section) to a unique value, or change the Request Path fields in all locations listed below:

Comment: @RakeshDonga Please share solution.

Answer (score 3):

There are so may issue is already reported on stack & GitHub and other community.  and there are so many solutions for that and which one is correct it is to difficult choosing the right one. but I see one issue is reported on GitHub which one help to you I think. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7298

This issue occurring due to duplicate entry on the database table `url_rewrite`, so there is only one way to resolve this issue you need to empty the table and regenerate the URL. so I have checked and found one answer which one usefull to me which I shared below.

---

**Note:** Take database backup before doing below opration.

Remove the duplication data when saving category. This data is throw in method **doReplace($urls)** in `\vendor\magento\module-url-rewrite\Model\Storage\DbStorage.php` file.

```
protected function doReplace($urls)
{
    foreach ($this->createFilterDataBasedOnUrls($urls) as $type => $urlData) {
        $urlData[UrlRewrite::ENTITY_TYPE] = $type;
        $this->deleteByData($urlData);
    }
    $data = [];
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        $data[] = $url->toArray();
    }
    $this->insertMultiple($data);
}
```

I  found out **$data** variable has a duplicate record. If you want this method to work without any errors. Rewrite this method above to below one.

```
protected function doReplace($urls) {
        foreach ($this->createFilterDataBasedOnUrls($urls) as $type => $urlData) {
            $urlData[UrlRewrite::ENTITY_TYPE] = $type;
            $this->deleteByData($urlData);
        }
        $data = [];
        $storeId_requestPaths = [];
        foreach ($urls as $url) {
            $storeId = $url->getStoreId();
            $requestPath = $url->getRequestPath();
            // Skip if is exist in the database
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM url_rewrite where store_id = $storeId and request_path = '$requestPath'";
            $exists = $this->connection->fetchOne($sql);

            if ($exists) continue;

            $storeId_requestPaths[] = $storeId . '-' . $requestPath;
            $data[] = $url->toArray();
        }

        // Remove duplication data;
        $n = count($storeId_requestPaths);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $n - 1; $i++) {
            for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $n; $j++) {
                if ($storeId_requestPaths[$i] == $storeId_requestPaths[$j]) {
                    unset($data[$j]);
                }
            }
        }
        $this->insertMultiple($data); 
}
```

Taje refrance from [Magento 2 Duplicate Product URLs Problem](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/258606/magento-2-duplicate-product-urls-problem) And ["URL key for specified store already exists." cannot save category #7298](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7298)
I hope it helps!

Comment: you are right @Chirag patel but default function is like : http://prntscr.com/o4sibb

Comment: There might be different code in function because of the different Magento version.  so you have debugged this code and I have shared logic `Remove duplication data;` try this

Comment: Just print `$data` variable of your function and check what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error while trying to make category "is_anchor".

**Solution:**

- Please click each of the  error message (highlighted URL) and delete.
- Refresh the page and save category again.

Comment: This is happening to me on trying to anchor a category.  I am not sure though I am understanding how you fixed it?

Comment: I am facing same error while trying to make category "is_anchor". Is there any proper solution. As i have migrated data from Magento 1 to Magento 2. So, i can not truncate the url_rewrite table as well. As there are defined all the redirection of the products and category as well.

Answer (score 1):

For the record - you most likely have duplicate product names. I had the same problem. You can check the error in `var/log/exception.log` to see exact url. Copy it.

Then you can check your database for duplicates with the following query:

```
select entity_id, request_path, store_id from url_rewrite where request_path like '%kreinik-metallic-very-fine-4-siulai%';
```

where the last part is your url. In the results you will see the request paths together with store_id and entity_id. In my case I had multiple entity_id with the same request_path. This helped me to track the problem.

You could also just search your catalog with the name of the product you are trying to save.

As a solution would be to update the URL generator so it would add SKU to the end of your urls.

Answer (score 0):

Please override with below two files : 
`module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/Product/AnchorUrlRewriteGenerator.php (Line 58)`

```
/**
 * Generate list based on categories
 *
 * @param int $storeId
 * @param Product $product
 * @param ObjectRegistry $productCategories
 * @return UrlRewrite[]
 */
 public function generate($storeId, Product $product, ObjectRegistry $productCategories)
 {
 $urls = [];
 foreach ($productCategories->getList() as $category) {
 $anchorCategoryIds = $category->getAnchorsAbove();
 if ($anchorCategoryIds) {
 foreach ($anchorCategoryIds as $anchorCategoryId) {
 //Default: $anchorCategory = $this->categoryRepository->get($anchorCategoryId);
 $anchorCategory = $this->categoryRepository->get($anchorCategoryId, $storeId);
 $urls[] = $this->urlRewriteFactory->create()
 ->setEntityType(ProductUrlRewriteGenerator::ENTITY_TYPE)
 ->setEntityId($product->getId())
 ->setRequestPath(
 $this->urlPathGenerator->getUrlPathWithSuffix(
 $product,
 $storeId,
 $anchorCategory
 )
 )
 ->setTargetPath(
 $this->urlPathGenerator->getCanonicalUrlPath(
 $product,
 $anchorCategory
 )
 )
 ->setStoreId($storeId)
 ->setMetadata(['category_id' => $anchorCategory->getId()]);
 }
 }
 }
return $urls;
 }
```

step2 : `module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/ProductUrlRewriteGenerator.php (Line 146)`

```
/**
     * Generate list of urls for global scope
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $productCategories
     *
     * @return \Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite[]
     */
     protected function generateForGlobalScope($productCategories)
     {
     $urls = [];
     $productId = $this->product->getEntityId();
     foreach ($this->product->getStoreIds() as $id) {
     if (!$this->isGlobalScope($id)
     && !$this->storeViewService->doesEntityHaveOverriddenUrlKeyForStore($id, $productId, Product::ENTITY)
     ) {
     // Default: $urls = array_merge($urls, $this->generateForSpecificStoreView($id, $productCategories));
     // before loading the category collection by looping it, clone it and set the correct store id,
     // so we get the correct url_path & url_key for that specific store id
     $storeSpecificProductCategories = clone $productCategories;
     $storeSpecificProductCategories->setStoreId($id);
    $urls = array_merge($urls, $this->generateForSpecificStoreView($id, $storeSpecificProductCategories));
     }
     }
     return $urls;
     }
```

Comment: please your code i have dont understand because your code in many <br> <p> available

Comment: check now, its code editor issue.

Comment: thanks ok let me check

Comment: not working for me

Comment: than please truncate url_rewrite table, than execute normal command which we are using.

Comment: you sure if i truncate above table and not any problem database and website

Comment: check please i send you one more answer to truncate table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95217/discussion-between-rakesh-donga-and-anas-mansuri).